# Where do you see player progression in franchise mode in Madden 2010?

Tags: madden-10

I started playing franchise mode and I don't know where I can see if a player improved after a few games. Also, how do I know how much he improved each stat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Players improve once per season, at the end of the season.

[Source](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090818152838AA4Yzka)